# UNITY Pixelated shadows

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

Hy everyone!
Im trying to write shader, which is making shadows on it look pixelated.
First I made shader like this (code below), but it's pixelating shadows in screen space.
Than I realized that I need to pass rounded uv world position to the _ShadowCoord, but I don't know how.
Can anybody help me?

```
v2f vert (appdata v)
        {
            v2f o;
            o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
            o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.uv, _MainTex);
            o._ShadowCoord = ComputeScreenPos(o.vertex);
            o.wPos = mul(unity_ObjectToWorld, v.vertex);
            return o;
        }

        fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
        {
            fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);
            
            float2 shadow_screen = i._ShadowCoord.xy / i._ShadowCoord.w;
            float map_dist = tex2D(_ShadowMapTexture, shadow_screen).r;
            float shadow_dist = mul(unity_WorldToShadow[0], i.wPos);
            
            if (shadow_dist>map_dist) return 0;
            
            return col;
        }
```